How to disable wasm secondary rendering of pages in blazor auto mode?
When a page is requested, server-side rendering is performed first, and then the browser displays the server-side rendered content. When the wasm download is completed, the page is rendered. If the rendering logic of the server and wasm are different, the page will flash.
For Example:
@if(imageID == 0)
{
    <img src="images/banner1.jpeg" class="w-full object-cover object-center">
}
else if(imageID == 1)
{
    <img src="images/banner2.jpeg" class="w-full object-cover object-center">
}
else 
{
    
}

@code{
    int imageID = -1;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        imageID = rd.Next(1, 1000) % 2;
    } 
} 

I want the page to be rendered only once but I don't find a way.
In addition to disabling wasm secondary rendering, are there any other methods?
thanks

We can use @rendermode @(new InteractiveAutoRenderMode(prerender: false)) to disable prerender which is enabled by default in interactive mode to avoid the OnInitialized being triggered twice.
============================
blazor auto mode shall be blazor web app Interactive Auto render mode in .net 8. We call it as blazor web app and auto mode will both have the client APP and the server APP, the client APP works as the wsam. Like screenshot below, the home page has @rendermode InteractiveServer, so that in the first loading, it doesn't have any wsam loaded. While the Counter Page will have wsam after I added @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly. The render mode is the difference.


And I didn't understand what If the rendering logic of the server and wasm are different, the page will flash. means, but for the page to be rendered only once, I'm afraid you are concerned about the prerendering feature of the Server Side rendered((wsam is rendered completely in the client side so that it doesn't have server side prerender).), because when we add a break point in the OnInitialized method, we will see it being triggered twice.
Then we can add @rendermode @(new InteractiveServerRenderMode(prerender: false)) to disable prerendering and the OnInitialized will be triggered only once.

Thanks Reply.
My page uses InteractiveAuto mode。
<img src="images/@img" class="w-full object-cover object-center">
step1
When I access the page through the browser, it is rendered by the server for the first time. At this time, OnInitialized is executed. @img is a random number, such as 1.
step2
After the wasm download is completed, OnInitialized is executed once, and @img may be 2.
Because the interval between step1 and step2 is relatively short, the browser displays 1.jpeg and 2.jpeg in sequence, which looks like flickering.

Thanks for your reply! Then you can try @rendermode @(new InteractiveAutoRenderMode(prerender: false)) instead of @rendermode InteractiveAuto. I reproduced your problem in my side and OnInitialized method will be triggered once after disableing prefernder. You can see this section: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-8.0#prerendering

Thanks for your reply! This method is ok, but it will cause more pressure on the server. I want more processing to be done on the client, server rendering as little as possible. This is also the original design intention of auto mode.

@boolean0011 I want more processing to be done on the client -> what we disabled is the server-side prerender but not the client side prerender. Client side doesn't prerender. When we disable the server side prerender, we are trying to reduce the server pressure.

The design purpose of auto mode is to use client-side rendering instead of server-side rendering as much as possible. Only when the client's wasm has not been downloaded, server-side rendering is temporarily used. After the wasm download is completed, it is better to not perform a second rendering of the page that has been displayed and rendered by the server.

before .net 8 we only have seperate wsam or sever render mode, wsam requires a wsam loading before the page rendering which might be not so friendly as it requires several seconds but it will bring benefits later since all the operations are handle by the client. While server side render are handled by the server so that the first time we opening the website, it won't cost much time to load wsam at the begining. When we have blazor web app in .net 8, we are able to integrate wsam and server render together to avoid the disadvantange of both and have the advantages of both.

maybe we can make the home page to use InteractiveServer and other pages to use InteractiveWebAssembly?  In the meantime, the "render for 2 times" is caused by prerender.

Thanks Reply. This has been resolved, it is indeed caused by pre rendering.

My page uses InteractiveAuto mode, like this
@page "/"
@rendermode InteractiveAuto

<img src="images/@img">

@code {
    string img;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        Random rd = new Random();
        r = rd.Next(1, 1000) % 2;
        img = String.Format("{0}.jpeg", r);
    }
}

step1
When I access the page through the browser, it is rendered by the server for the first time. At this time, OnInitialized is executed. @img is a random number, such as 1.
step2
After the wasm download is completed, OnInitialized is executed once, and @img may be 2.
Because the interval between step1 and step2 is relatively short, the browser displays 1.jpeg and 2.jpeg in sequence, which looks like flickering.
